# SQL SUM() from multiple tables using c# EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datagridview

I want to show Monthly total for each department as I'm able to show the name of departments which have made some purchase but I can't show their total amount which is in two different tables.

```
    var MA = db.Months.Where(m => m.Month_Name == MA_MonthCombobox.Text)
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    MA_DN = m.Vehical.Department.Dept_Name,
                    MA_Amount = m.Fule_Bill.LB_GTAmount
                }).ToList();

            MA_DetailsDataGridView.DataSource = MA;
```

so this is my code please help me with this thanks in advance...

**DATABASE TABLES AND RELATIONS**
[Database tables and relations](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhchZSm5cWnMUFBQ00zUFE2Nms/edit?usp=sharing)

**OUTPUT DATAGRIDVIEW TO SHOW RESULTS**
[DataGridView](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhchZSm5cWnYk81OVlzSzBLbms/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is the keyword `.Sum( t => t.ColumnToSum)` that you can use, or did you already tried it?

Comment: Sounds like `Fule_Bill` is null or `LB_GTAmount` is 0.

Comment: Why not `m.Fule_Bill.LB_GTAmount + m.Lubricant_Bill.LB_GTAmount`?

Comment: Zaphod, I did not get .Sum() functionality and how to exactly use it please help me out with it

Comment: tschmit007, Yes it give null value error but I failed to figure it out how to solve it

Comment: Gert Arnold, I've already tried this it gives me error of null value...